# ng-show if filter and inner if statements are valid

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat being created like so:

```
<div class="items">
  <!-- WANT TO HIDE THIS ENTIRE AREA IF THERE IS NO VALID ITEMS -->
  <b>Items</b>
  <span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'priority'" itemid="{{item.$id}}" ng-if="!item.groupID || item.groupID == 'misc'">
   {{item.title}}
  </span>
</div>
```

As you can see I have an `ng-if` which checks if the item has a `null` `item.groupid` or is in the `misc` category.

Many times there is no items that match all of these criteria and in that case I want to hide the outer div `<div class="items">`

I can't figure out how to hide it because I can't do an ng-show on the inner elements part of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter, and assign the result of the filter to a variable. Use that variable to decide if the enclosing `div` should be shown or not.

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBsICQDGLzT7T9ZvDANE?p=preview) showing how it works:

```
<div ng-show="filteredItems.length > 0">
  Test
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:hasGroupFilter(group) as filteredItems">
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.group }}
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.hasGroupFilter = function(group) {
  return function(item) {
    return !item.group || item.group === group;
  };
};
```

Comment: I tried this, the $scope.hasGroupFilter function never fires

Comment: Actually nevermind, had a typo, this is working great.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way to do that is to pre filter the list, and add a condition on your parent div.items instead of using ng-if in each one of the span in the ng-repeat.

[Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8gNTnG)

You should filter the list in your controller and just add the condition on the parent div

```
 <div class="items" ng-if="filteredItems.length">
   <b>Items</b>
   <span ng-repeat="item in filteredItems | orderBy:'priority'" itemid="{{item.$id}}">
    {{item.title}}
   </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pre-filter the list or this way would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially create a function that has access to a public variable on the outer scope. It would look something along the lines of this:

Inside your JS file

```
$scope.NoValidItems = true; //assume no valid items code also might look different based on how you format your angular
$scope.CheckItems = function(item){
var check = false;
    if(item.groupID && item.groupID !== 'misc'){
        check = true;
        $scope.NoValidItems = false;
    }else
      check = false;
    return check;
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="items" ng-if="!NoValidItems ">
<!-- WANT TO HIDE THIS ENTIRE AREA IF THERE IS NO VALID ITEMS -->
<b>Items</b>
<span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'priority'" itemid="{{item.$id}}" ng-if="!CheckItems(item)">
   {{item.title}}
  </span>
</div>
```

This should work, and the if statement might not be exact, but you get the drift. Pretty much if there is one that is valid it will show, but if there is not a valid item do not show. Valid being meeting your conditional criteria. Hopefully this helps, and I explained it alright